# Can healthy be use in every circumstances in stead of healthful?

Tags: word-usage

From what I found, *healthy* can have the meaning of *healthful*, moreover the Oxford dictionary consider them as synonyms since 1552 (according to an unverified source). However, there still seems to be a big fuss about *healthy* being used in place of *healthful*.

I did not know about *healthful* until fairly recently and have been using *healthy* with the very meaning of *healthful* in a lot of occasions without being told that I was off.

Therefore, I would be glad if you could show evidence that *healthful* is not a word redundant with *healthy*.

Nota: I am aware that there are two questions addressing this very problem on ELU but the answers were lacking solid conclusions.

Comment: "Healthful" is not a word I would ever use. I would expect to see it in advertising medical preparations and nowhere else. It appears 1553 times in GloWbE, against 146158 times for "healthy".

Comment: @ColinFine That confirms that *healthful* is clearly not an every-day word.

Comment: My mother taught me a lot of prescriptive rules when I was little, and she taught me to say *healthful* instead of *healthy* in that context.  But it sounds strange, so I stopped doing it after she stopped making me do it :-)  I don't think I ever say *healthful* in any context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want me to produce evidence that healthful is not redundant with healthy, I'm afraid that I have to disappoint you.

According to the Cambridge Dictionary,

[healthy](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/healthy) has three meanings related to physical wellbeing:

- ​strong and well
- showing that you are strong and well
- good for ​your ​health

[healthful](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/healthful?q=Healthful) has just one meaning:

- helping to ​produce good ​health

**Healthful** covers only one of the possible wellbeing-related meanings of **healthy** - the third one. This meaning can only be applied to things that promote health (foods, exercise etc). Its meaning and scope of usage are therefore identical to **healthful**.

This [NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=healthful%20foods%2Chealthy%20foods%2Chealthy%20exercise%2Chealthful%20exercise&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Chealthful%20foods%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chealthy%20foods%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chealthy%20exercise%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chealthful%20exercise%3B%2Cc0) demonstrates that, if there is "a big fuss about healthy being used in place of healthful", the people who are making the big fuss are fighting a losing battle.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I can now forget both about healthful and the fuss around those two words.